# Java recursion sum of number non divisible by specific number

Tags: java, recursion, sum

I have to find sum of the all even numbers that are not divisible by 7 using recursion. I tried this code but it seems I am making mistake somewhere because it returns 0:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println(specialSum(50));
}
public static int specialSum(int a) {

    if ((a >= 1) && ((specialSum(a-1))%7 !=0)) {
        return a + specialSum(a -1);
    } else{
        return 0;
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, recursion means that you continue to iterate until you hit an ultimate condition. This condition is your `else`, and then you just return 0. You probably want to pass the current sum into the method.

Comment: @ChrisWohlert there is no need to pass the current sum into the method. check my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have the solution in one line, you should have a case to stop the recursion, in your case you stop the recursion at 49 because it is divisible by 7, and you don't take into account numbers less than 49

```
main()
{
    specialSum(50, 7);
}

 public static int specialSum(int a, int toDivide)
 {
    return (a == 0) ? 0 : (a >= 1 && a%2 == 0 && a%7 != 0) ? a + specialSum(a - 1, toDivide) : specialSum(a - 1, toDivide);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if ((a >= 1) && ((specialSum(a-1))%7 !=0))` try `if ((a >= 1) && (a%7) !=0))`, as it is now, you're never checking if the original `a` value is not divisible by 7, your first check is always `a` - 1.

Answer (score 1):

In recursion, you just need to focus on current step, you shouldn't user specialSum(a -1) in a condition. This is the next step, you should only call it after focusing on the current step.

You should just apply your two rules to succeed : add the current number to the nexts only 
- if they are even
- if they are not divisible by 7.

```
public static int specialSum(int a) {
    if(a <= 1) // Final Case.  
    {
        System.out.print(" 0 = ");
        return 0;
    }


    if(a%2 != 0) // Even Number, do not sum, call next step
    {
        return specialSum(a-1);
    }
    else 
    { 
        if(a % 7 == 0){ // Divisible by 7  Do not sum, call next step.
            return specialSum(a-1);
        }
        else // NOT divisible by 7 nor by 2, add it to the next step
        {
            System.out.print(a+ " + ");
            return a + specialSum(a-1);
        }

    }

}
```

outputs : 
    50 + 48 + 46 + 44 + 40 + 38 + 36 + 34 + 32 + 30 + 26 + 24 + 22 + 20 + 18 + 16 + 12 + 10 + 8 + 6 + 4 + 2 +  0 = 566

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.

The condition `(specialSum(a-1))%7 !=0)` in your code calls the method for `49`, when `a=50`. This calls the method for `48`, which calls for `47` and so on until `a=1`. Then, it calls for `0`, which is **not greater than or equal to** `1`, and hence it returns `0`. Now, `0%n` for any number, is `0`. Hence, you get `0` as the output.

Change your method to something like this:

```
public static int specialSum(int a) {
    if(a<=2) return 2; // base case
    else if(a%7==0) return specialSum(a-2); // if it is divisible by 7, then do not add it, and call the method for a-2.
    else return a+specialSum(a-2); // else add the number, and get the answer for a-2.
}
```

Comment: What about calling the function with values <= 0? (Would return 2 in your example). Also, not sure what "a%2==7" is supposed to check...shouldn't that be "a%7==0"?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. The first `if` makes sure to only take even numbers. Then second `if` makes sure only to sum if not divisible by 7. The last `if` sums the result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(specialSum(50, 0));
}

public static int specialSum(int max, int current){
    if(max % 2 == 1)
        max -= 1;
    if(max % 7 != 0)
        current += max;
    if(max >= 1){
        max -= 2;
        return specialSum(max, current);
    }
    return current;
}
```

This returns 566.
Equal to: 50 + 48 + 46 + 44 + 40 + 38 + 36 + 34 + 32 + 30 + 26 + 24 + 22 + 20 + 18 + 16 + 12 + 10 + 8 + 6 + 4 + 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int specialSum(int a) {

      if ( a % 7 !=0 && a%2==0 ) {
        return a + specialSum(a - 2);
    } else {
        if (a > 2  ) {
            a=a-2;
            return a + specialSum(a - 2);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This throws a StackOverflowException. You can't return from it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if a is divisible by 7, so you should use `if ((a>=1) && (a%7) !=0))` to make sure that the you check for the base condition.